# efficient iteration over long vector

Tags: matlab, vector, loops

I have a long vector, containing > 1 million entries, distributed according to a probability density function (Gaussian). I only need the positive values, and these I find as in the following MWE

```
N = 1.5e6;
vals = normrnd(0, 1, N, 1);

final = [];
for i=1:length(vals)
    if(vals(i)>0)
        final = [final vals(i)];
    end
end
```

The problem is that this takes a long time. Is there a smarter way to do this in MatLAB?

Thanks,
Niles.

Comment: @jerad's answer is probably what you want.  What you have written yourself is just about the slowest approach you could possibly take without deliberately inserting long periods of sleep into your code !  You first create an empty array called `final`.  At each iteration you allocate (though you don't seem to have realised this) a new block of space labelled `first` into which you copy the existing elements of `first` and a new element, then release the space for the old version of `first` back into the free pool.  Looping through a long vector is fast, but repeated memory allocation is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove the negative numbers without a for loop in matlab:

```
vals = normrnd(0, 1, N, 1);
vals(vals<0) = [];
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to loop, just pick out the positive values.

```
final = vals( vals>0 );
```

**EDIT:**
Out of interest, I timed the two approaches. Assigning to a new variable is about twice as quick as removing elements. That said, they're both very fast:

```
>> N = 1.5e6;
>> vals = normrnd(0, 1, N, 1);
>> tic; final = vals( vals>0 ); toc
Elapsed time is 0.020852 seconds.
>> tic; vals(vals<0) = []; toc
Elapsed time is 0.041709 seconds.
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the reasons your script is being slow is because you didn't initialized `final` previously. So, the variable is growing inside the loop. Initialize your variables first if you know its size *a priori*:

```
N = 1.5e6;
vals = normrnd(0, 1, N, 1);

final = zeros(vals,1);
for i=1:length(vals)
    if(vals(i)>0)
        final(i) = vals(i);
    end
end
```

But, the main reason is because you're using a loop and you can perform this operations using logical indexing:

```
final = vals( vals > 0 )
```